# Check if column exists in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

table_1

```
customer   item  price
Andy       Doll   50
Bella      Robot  25
```

table_2

```
customer_name  address 
Andy           Baker Street, London
Carlos         Huntington Street, Newcastle
```

I would like to create a new column based on whether the value in table_1 exists in table_2.
Expected output

```
customer.   exists_in_table_2
Andy            Yes
Bella           No
```

My code so far:

```
select customer, 
case when customer in (select customer_name from table_2) then 'Yes'
else 'No' end as exists_in_table_2
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

How efficient the query is depends on the database you are using. I usually recommend `exists` with the appropriate indexes.  That would be:

```
select t1.*, 
       (case when exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.customer = t2.customer_name)
             then 'Yes' else 'No'
        end) as exists_in_table_2
from table1 t1;
```

The appropriate index is on `table2(customer_name)`.